# Getting configparser.DuplicateOptionError: option 'pyramid.includes' in section 'app:main' already exists

Tags: pycharm, pyramid

I have installed pycharm professional version today. I have created new project with pyramid with starter scaffold. Now while trying to run this project it gives following error.

configparser.DuplicateOptionError: While reading from 'C:\Users\Pinkesh\PycharmProjects\todo2\development.ini' [line 15]: option 'pyramid.includes' in section 'app:main' already exists

[Click here to see pyramid configparser.DuplicateOptionError error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I47e.png)

Comment: Would you please submit a bug report to JetBrains on PyCharm for this issue? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In development.ini
Change from :

```
pyramid.includes = pyramid_jinja2

use = egg:untitled1

pyramid.reload_templates = true
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en
pyramid.includes = pyramid_debugtoolbar
```

To:

```
pyramid.includes = pyramid_jinja2
                   pyramid_debugtoolbar
use = egg:untitled1

pyramid.reload_templates = true
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en
```

Now run setup.py develop and then run development.ini
And issue resolved.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your development.ini file.  There is an extra 'includes chameleon".  Just take one of them out.

I believe this is a bug in pycharm.  I have to remember to remove it also everytime I start a new project also.